# Trouble getting file path in Netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm making a program that uses text files. I need to make it so that the program can be run from a different computer using its jar file. The problem is that I can't get it to find the right file path to the text files. I've tried using `getResource()`, but it's still not working right. Here's the code:

```
public class Params {

    public static void init() {

        hsChartSuited = new int[13][13];

        file = new File(Params.class.getResource("HandStrengthDataSuited.txt").getFile());

        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            for (int i = 0; i < hsChartSuited.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < hsChartSuited[i].length; j++) {
                    hsChartSuited[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(input.next()) - 20;
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");

        }
}
```

`HandStrengthDataSuited.txt` is a file that is in the src folder for my project. It's also located outside of the folder, in the project's main directory as well. I've tried printing the absolute file path, and this is what I get:

```
/Users/MyUsername/file:/Users/MyUsername/Documents/Homework_Soph_2012/Computer%20Science/HoldEm/dist/HoldEm.jar!/holdem/HandStrengthDataSuited.txt
```

The file path that I need to get is

```
/Users/MyUsername/Documents/Homework_Soph_2012/Computer%20Science/HoldEm/holdem/HandStrengthDataSuited.txt
```

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files is in src folder,

```
class Tools {
    public static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resource)
        throws FileNotFoundException
         {
        String stripped = resource.startsWith("/") ? resource.substring(1) : resource;
        InputStream stream = null;
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if (classLoader != null) {
          stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(stripped);
        }
        if (stream == null) {
          stream = Tools.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);
        }
        if (stream == null) {
          stream = Tools.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(stripped);
        }
        if (stream == null) {
          throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + resource);
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResourceAsStream("org/paulvargas/resources/file.txt"), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: So, do I replace `org/paulvargas/resources/file.txt` with `src/holdem/HandStrengthDataSuited.txt` then?

Comment: Only with `holdem/HandStrengthDataSuited.txt` if `src` not is java packet.